# Example 1.36 in Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold.

Tags: manifolds, grassmannian

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional real vector space decomposed as a direct sum: $V=P\oplus Q$, with $\dim P=k$ and $\dim Q=n-k$. The graph of any linear map $X:P\rightarrow Q$ can be identified with a k-dimensional subspace $\Gamma(X)=\{v+Xv : v\in P\}$. Any such subspace has the property that its intersection with Q is the zero subspace.

I don't understand the last sentence. How can $\Gamma(X)$ not intersect $Q$ if its elements are a linear superposition of elements from $v\in P$ and $Xv\in Q$?

Comment: For $v\in P$ with $v+Xx\in Q$ implies $v=(v+Xv) - Xv\in Q$, since $Xv\in Q$, and $P\cap Q=\{0\}$. To aid your intuition, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ all non-vertical lines intersect the $Y$-axis only at the origin. And the result concerns only non-vertical lines passing through the origin.